# Elements of this output

Tags: python, list, element

This is the code I have but I'm having trouble figuring out the elements in the list daysOfWeek...

```
daysOfWeek = ["Friday", "Tuesday"]
daysOfWeek.append("Monday" * 3)
daysOfWeek = daysOfWeek + list("Sat")
del daysOfWeek[-2]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: If I execute this code, what are the elements in daysOfWeek?

Comment: do you want to view the content of daysOfWeek?

Comment: This is Python. Open an interactive interpreter and run it. Follow each line with `print(daysOfWeek)` and you'll see it step by step.

Comment: Please make sure,when you ask question, it should be clearly illustrative, and also the difficulty you are facing in solving.

Comment: Try printing `daysOfWeek` to find out what it does.

Comment: `print daysOfWeek` ? : /

Comment: ['Friday', 'Tuesday', 'MondayMondayMonday', 'S', 't'] this is the output, what are the elements?

Comment: `'Friday'`, `'Tuesday'`, `'MondayMondayMonday'`, `'S'`, and `'t'`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `print(daysOfWeek)` at the end of your code.

Then you'll be able to see the content of daysOfWeek.

```
daysOfWeek = ["Friday", "Tuesday"]     # ["Friday", "Tuesday"]
daysOfWeek.append("Monday" * 3)        # ['Friday', 'Tuesday', 'MondayMondayMonday']
daysOfWeek = daysOfWeek + list("Sat")  # ['Friday', 'Tuesday', 'MondayMondayMonday', 'S', 'a', 't']
del daysOfWeek[-2]                     # ['Friday', 'Tuesday', 'MondayMondayMonday', 'S', 't']
print(daysOfWeek)                      
# You would see ['Friday', 'Tuesday', 'MondayMondayMonday', 'S', 't'] as the result
```

Comment: does this mean Friday, Tuesday, MondayMondayMonday, S, t, are my elements? I'm confused...

Comment: Yes those are the elements.

Comment: Yes, I've edited my answer to explain what happened during the execution.